# C# documentation strings: Parameter of an Action property

Tags: c#, documentation

I'm documenting c# code right now. I have this interface which exposes an `Action<string>` property.

```
interface IFoo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Will be called when Bar happens
    /// </summary>
    /// <action_parameter_1_or_something>
    /// Can be a string or null.
    /// If not null, the message must be displayed.
    /// If null, the message must be cleared.
    /// </action_parameter_1_or_something>
    Action<string> OnBarHappened { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to document the parameter that will be given to the `Action`. Obviously, my sensibly named tag, `action_parameter_1_or_something` doesn't exist.

How would you document that?

Comment: Usually I just make sreenshot of the code with some overlay text written with mspaint and upload that to my dropbox in a folder name "doc", then share it by email to various collaborators. Best way to document code.

Comment: Why do you need to document anything? If all you are going to say is that its going to be `string` or `null`, thats already imposed by the type of the delegate itself: `Action<string>`.

Comment: You can add extra info in a <remark></remark> block

Comment: @GilSand I'm genuinely concerned because I can't tell if you are joking or not

Comment: You can add all needed information right inside `<summary>`. From other point of view, who will be looking at that information? The one who use property will only care it's `Action<string>` type, intellisense prevent user from doing stupid mistake and compiler doesn't care about name of parameter.

Comment: A type-parameter can´t be null. However do you mean `Action<T>` instead of `Action<string>`? Then you could use the `paramref`-tag for this

Comment: @InBetween makes sense, but there's a specific expectation as to what should happen when the parameter is null or not null. I want to document that expectation.

Comment: @aspyct You could do that in the summary. Still, if the expectations and way things should be handled are different if the string is null or not, maybe a better design would be having to distinct properties, one typed `Action` and another `Action<string>`, and the correct one would be invoked in each case.

Comment: My comment should have read <remarks> : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3zw4z1ys.aspx

Comment: "Why do you need to document anything?"  Well, Action<string> tells you it's a string, but doesn't tell you if that string holds an error message, the name of a file, the name of a parameter to investigate, etc.  If types were all you needed to know then (outside of inheritance issues) no one would ever document any parameter ever.

Answer (score 1):

I use Sandcastle Help File Builder to build my documents.  I actually ran into the exact same issue that you did.  SHFB does not support this out of the gate, but I have an issue in there where I talk through how I personally added these tags to the output of what he did.  Basically you have to add you tag to a couple of XML transforms then it will show up in your documentation.

https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB

https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB/issues/199

That is the specific issue I had opened.  This then automatically shows up on our API documentation and can be used to include any tag set we use.  One of the things we use this for is the Data Type,  m, m/s, m^3 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've explained in the comments, I'll try to give you an answer... Start with the concept of what the property represents and what it does. Give your property a name based on that. Then, use the tags in the MSDN site (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax.aspx) to put your explanations in whichever format you prefer. Personally, I'd just place a brief description in the summary block. You don't want to get too extended when documenting a property. I.E.: "Normally a string. If null, does XYZ".